# Inverse of a symmetric matrix in which upper triangular elements for a given column are equal to the corresponding diagonal element

Tags: matrices, inverse

I've been studying a symmetric matrix with the following form:

$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    a_1    & a_2    & a_3    & a_4    & \cdots & a_n \\
    a_2    & a_2    & a_3    & a_4    & \cdots & a_n \\
    a_3    & a_3    & a_3    & a_4    & \cdots & a_n \\
    a_4    & a_4    & a_4    & a_4    & \cdots & a_n \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    a_n    & a_n    & a_n    & a_n    & \cdots & a_n
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

where $a_i > 0$ for $i = 1, \dots, n$.

I was curious if a matrix with this form has been described previously and, if so, what properties it has, particularly its inverse.

Comment: Note the $(i,j)$ entry is equal to $a_{\max(i,j)}$.

Comment: Did you try for the $2 \times 2$ and $3 \times 3$ cases?

Comment: Hint: Try Guassian Elimination

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Denote the given matrix by $S_n$.

> $S_n^{-1}$ exists if and only if $a_n \neq 0$ and $a_i \neq a_{i-1} ~\forall~ i=2,...,n$.

To see this perform elementary row operations to transform the given matrix to

$$\left[
\begin{matrix}
    a_1 & a_2 & a_3 &\cdots & a_n \\
    a_2-a_1 & 0 & 0& \cdots & 0 \\
    a_3-a_1 & a_3-a_2 & 0 &\cdots & 0 \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
    a_n-a_1 & a_n-a_2 & a_n-a_3 & \cdots & 0 \\
    \end{matrix}
\right]$$

Now expanding the determinant along the last column we get

$$\text{det}(S_n)=(-1)^{1+n}a_n\prod_{i=2}^{n} (a_i-a_{i-1})$$
from which the above property is apparent.

Also, note that the leading principal submatrix of $S_n$ could be thought of as $S_{n-1}$ which could lead to nice proofs by induction.